# Where types should be checked, in ANTLR grammar or in the visitor?

Tags: java, antlr4

One part of my grammar in ANTRL are boolean expressions. At the moment, *expr* just works for strings.

```
bool_expr
 : '(' bool_expr ')'             #boolParenOp
 | left=expr oper=OP right=expr  #boolOp
 | TRUE                          #boolAtom
 | FALSE                         #boolAtom
 ;

expr
 : attributeAccess
 | STRING
 ;
```

If I want to add integers or numbers to *bool_expr*, should I check the types in the grammar, adding more rules like "*left=num_expr oper=OP right=num_expr*" or check the contents of "*expr*" in the visitor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encoding types in the grammar¹ does not scale well. The more types you add, the more grammar rules you need, and as soon as you have more than a fixed amount of built-in types (say you allow tuple-types or even user-definable types), it becomes plain impossible.

And even without that, there's plenty of opportunities to run into issues. For example let's say you add variables and functions (or any of many other possible features) to the language. Are variables and function calls `bool_expr`s or `int_expr`s or both? Unless you want to restrict variables and functions to one type only, it'd need to be both. Same for function arguments. But now your grammar is ambiguous. Say you have `f(x)` as an expression. It is impossible to know whether `x` is a `bool_expr` or an `int_expr` just from that expression - you'd have to know how `x` was defined (which would require context sensitivity).

So it's much more robust to just have an expression rule that can match expressions of all types in the grammar and perform type checking on the tree as a separate step.

---

¹ That is, structuring the grammar in such a way that you can know the type of an expression by knowing which productions it matched and that all generated expressions are type-correct by construction.

Comment: I disagree. It's pretty common to add individual rules for each supported type, e.g. in a [`literal`](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/8.0/library/parsers/grammars/MySQLParser.g4#L3569) rule, which contains definitions for strings, numbers, bool values and even more specialized datatypes (like temporal values in this grammar). User datatypes are usually defined as extension of base types, which a grammar can parse anyway.

Comment: @Mike Do you have a link to a grammar that would back this up ?

Comment: @sepp2k how that would be handled in the method of a visitor ?

Comment: @MikeLischke Would you post your comment and example as an answer ?

Comment: @MikeLischke I think we're talking about different things. The OP was asking whether type checking should be handled as a separate phase or whether the grammar should be constructed in such a way that type errors are syntax errors (i.e. have a rule that can only match expressions of type `bool` and one for expressions of type `string` etc. - like the grammar in the question). I'm saying that the latter is not feasible for non-trivial grammars (and I'd be quite surprised if you actually disagree with that). I was not saying that you can't have rules for integer or string literals.

Comment: @jordiburgos You mean how a visitor would know the type of `x`? It'd simply keep an environment that maps variable names to their types. So if see a declaration (`bool x;`) we add `x: bool` to the environment for the current scope. And then if we see `f(x)`, we get the types of `f` and `x` from the environment and verify that the type of `x` matches the argument type of `f`.

Comment: @sepp2k yes, maybe just a misunderstanding. What I meant was that you will often find grammar rules for specific data types, e.g. see the [C grammar in the ANTLR4 grammar directory](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/c/C.g4#L686) or [my MySQL grammar](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/8.0/library/parsers/grammars/MySQLParser.g4#L3569).

Comment: @MikeLischke I've clarified the phrasing of my answer. I hope that makes it less prone to misunderstandings. Note that nothing in the grammars you linked would prevent, say, an integer literal to be used in a context where a Boolean was expected - that is the grammar does not remove the need for a type checker (which is what I meant by "encoding types in the grammar" and what OP was asking about).